# How to create a shortcut for a Unicode special character in Lotus 8.5?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, unicode, lotus-notes, special-characters

How do I create just one-click shortcut for Unicode special characters, like Alt+P for section symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom toolbar button to put in the special character, but I don't think you could tie a keyboard shortcut to it.

You could probably use something like AutoHotKey to do exactly what you want though.